# CS50 pset4 recover: Seg-fault in fwrite function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

A segmentation fault occurs whenever I run the program. Using printf functions, I have narrowed down that the seg-fault occurs in my fwrite function in the last line of code fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), block, output) in the first iteration of the second while loop. I've tried a lot of things, but I can't get the seg-fault to go away. Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

const int block = 512;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./recover card.raw");
    return 1;
}

//open file for reading
char *infile = argv[1];
FILE *file = fopen(infile, "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening file");
    return 1;
}
//initializing
BYTE buffer[block];
memset(buffer, 0x00, block);
BYTE x = 0;
memset(&x, 0x00, 1);
BYTE JPEG[3] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};
char filename[8];
int imagecount = 0;

//open file output for writing
FILE* output = NULL;
output = fopen("000.jpg", "w");
while (1)
{
    fread(&x, sizeof(BYTE), 1, file);
    if (x == JPEG[0])
    {
        fread(&x, sizeof(BYTE), 1, file);
        if (x == JPEG[1])
        {
            fread(&x, sizeof(BYTE), 1, file);
            if (x == JPEG[2])
            {
                fread(&x, sizeof(BYTE), 1, file);
                int y = (int) x;
                if ((y >= 224) && (y <= 239))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
fwrite(JPEG, sizeof(BYTE), 3, output);
fwrite(&x, sizeof(BYTE), 1, output);
fread(output, sizeof(BYTE), block - 4, file);
while (1)
{
    int n = fread(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), block, file);
    if (n == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (buffer[0] == JPEG[0] && buffer[1] == JPEG[1] && buffer[2] == JPEG[2] && output != NULL)
    {
        fclose(output);
        imagecount++;
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", imagecount);
        output = fopen(filename, "w");
    }
    printf("z");
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), block, output);
    printf("z");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing an `fread(output,...,...,file)`

That is, you are reading into a buffer that is your `output` FILE descriptor. Probably not what you intended ...

Note that the first argument to `fread` is a `void *` pointer, so it's perfectly happy to accept that (i.e. no compile error).

In other words, you are *trashing* what `FILE *output` points to.

Comment: Thank you so much! The seg-fault is gone now, and the program works perfectly. I still don't properly understand why I can't directly copy from file into output using fread. Please excuse my lack of understanding of the fread function, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: The model is `fread/fwrite` that takes a stream pointer, buffer pointer, and length. Likewise for the syscalls `read/write` [which are _faster_]. This is normally sufficient for most applications that want to: `read, do some processing on data, output _modified_ data`. That is the usual. But, for super high speed copying of files, there is a `sendfile` syscall [or `copy_file_range`]. That may be what you're thinking of. But, most of the time, the separate `read` then `write` is more general/flexible. And, usually, pretty fast. Likely, the limiting factor is the disk speed, so a moot point